# JavaScript: "$" not a function errors

Tags: javascript, function

I inherited this code on a Shopify site. Moving it and some related code into a new theme based on Dawn. Don't think the theme is the issue at all but rather this code which is now triggering a "$" is not a function error. Here's an example of that code:

```
$('.section__choose-texture').on('click', '.content', function ( ){
  var current = $(this);

  $('.content').removeClass('active');
  current.addClass('active');

  $('#prodTextureItem').val(current.data('texture'));
  $('#productTexture').text(current.find('h3').text());
  $('.section__choose-coffee').show();

  var header_height = $('.site-header').height(),
      offset_top = $('.section__choose-coffee').offset().top,
      res = offset_top - header_height;

  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: res }, 'slow');
});
```

I added a "function stepOne() {" to the top and then closed it with a } followed by a call to the function but Shopify's editor says it is bad code. I think that's because function is listed on line one of my example.

So how can I make this function work properly? Does the code need to be completely rewritten? Or was I on the correct path on my idea?

Comment: Is Jquery available in the scope of your code?

Comment: How is `I added a "function stepOne() {" to the top and then closed it with a } followed by a call to the function but Shopify's editor says it is bad code.` related to `which is now triggering a "$" is not a function error.` please limit yourself to one problem at time per question.

Comment: $ is standard JQuery statement

Comment: if your getting that error then you have not included jquery or you have included your code before jquery.. wrap your code in `(function ($) { // your code here })(jQuery || $);`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone
 how would your immediately invoiced function solve `you have included you code before jquery`, it would solve the problem if jQuery is loaded with `noConflict` but besides that it won’t help if jQuery is loaded later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use $ statement you have to add [jquery](https://jquery.com/) files or reference to the project.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

or [from jquery.com](https://code.jquery.com/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks to both Faith as well as Johannes. Didn't realize the theme had no references to jQuery. Guess I'm so used to that by now.

Answer (score 0):

The $ function is not a JavaScript built-in.

It comes from the [jQuery library](https://jquery.com/).

Add this script tag before your script to import it:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```